# Months shown are gregorian in Hijri Material UI date picker

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, hijri

I am using material UI datepicker and we have option to show Hijri calendar. The issue is with the months shown in the month picker are gregorian (arabic translation of January, February etc) while the correct one should be Muharram, Safar etc.. How do I get the Hijri months in it? I saw a codesandbox with same issue which I will link here - https://codesandbox.io/s/7vx23?file=/src/App.js?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I extended HijriUtils library to get Hijri months. In Month View, utils.format(date, 'MMM') is used to get the months (this is mi-ui-datepicker version - 3.3.10 which is compatible with material-ui 4.x version (latest stable), datepicker is part of material-ui from 5.x(still in beta)), moment hijri months format is 'iMMM'. I added format method to do it in Hijri way. Also we need getMonthArray, setMonth methods in HijriUtils to get/set months correctly.

```
export default class HijriUtilsExtended extends HijriUtils {
// Get the months array in hijri.
    getMonthArray = function (date) {
      const firstMonth = date.clone().locale(this.locale).startOf("iYear");
      const monthArray = [firstMonth];
  
        while (monthArray.length < 12) {
          const prevMonth = monthArray[monthArray.length - 1];
          monthArray.push(prevMonth.clone().add(1, "iMonth"));
        }
  
        return monthArray;
    }
    // Set month in Hijri.
    setMonth = function (date, count) {
        return date.clone().iMonth(count);
    };
     
    format = function (date, format) {
      return format === 'MMM' ? date.format('iMMM') : date.format(format);
    }
}
```

Here is the updated codesandbox link -
https://codesandbox.io/s/material-hijri-calendar-forked-y9e68?file=/src/App.js